# Directory creation using mkdir and touch

Tags: command-line, bash, mkdir

I need to create directory structure using `mkdir` for directory creation and `touch` for creating files using only relative paths.

[image: 1]

Comment: i have attached the image.For that i have create directory structure

Comment: Is this some kind of homework? We can help you, but it is not a good idea that we do the homework for you. Please try, and show the commands that you have tried. (Edit your original question. Indent each line with code with 4 spaces to render it as `code`.)

Comment: You can use `-p` switch for `mkdir` to create path of folders. `mkdir -p mydir/colors/basic`. Still You will have to do this few times to create entire structure.

Answer (score 3):

Using bash brace expansion to create the directory structure:

```
$ mkdir -p mydir/{colors/{basic,blanded},shape,animals/{mammals,reptiles}} && \
touch mydir/{colors/{basic/{red,blue,green},blanded/{yellow,orange,pink}},shape/{circle,square,cube},animals/{mammals/{platypus,bat,dog},reptiles/{snakes,crocodile,lizard}}}
```

<sup>You can examine the directory structure with the `tree` command.</sup>